# Method missing in tutorial

Tags: ios, tableview, method-missing

I'm new in the iOS programming, so I've followed one of Apple's Developer library-tutorials. In the "Implementing an app - Tutorial: Add data" part, the site wants me to change the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. The thing is, there is no method like that in "XYZToDoListTableViewController.m". Am I doing something wrong, or what? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // your code

    // return cell;
}
```

Comment: There is no default. You must implement this method of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

Comment: I thought of that, but then I wondered if the order of the methods meant anything (as I said: I`m a newbe). But thanks a lot :D. I`ll just do that.